# Winforms and it's version number

Tags: c#, winforms

I got a winforms application that works, and is published fine.

The thing is, the version I got into the publish folders are still in the scheme : `1.0.0.1`, while in the AssemblyInfo.cs, I got this :

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.1.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.1.*")]
```

I know I must change myself the first part `1.1` when it comes, but I was thinking, with this, I obtain `1.1.1`, `1.1.2` and not `1.0.0.1`, `1.0.0.2`.

I am doing a CLickOnce publish.

How can I choose a little more the version number?

Can somebody explain how it works?

Thank you.

Comment: You should have a better knowledge of the version number you publish than simply *whatever Visual Studio picked for me* . Ditch the asterix syntax and specify the exact version numbers.

Comment: But this doesn't change the fact that I still got a four number version, while I specify 3 numbers in the AssemblyInfo.

Comment: `*` does not mean 1 number, it means add whatever is missing. A version number consists of 4 numbers.

Comment: Ah ok. I was thinking 3 numbers versions were possible.

Comment: ClickOnce uses its own version numbering, independent from the version numbers in your assembly.  It is in plain view when you use Project + Properties, Publish.  And up to you to increment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ClickOnce uses its own version numbering, independent from the version numbers in your assembly.  Hard to miss in the Project + Properties, Publish tab unless you need to scroll:

[image]

Comment: It is exaclty that. The publish menu were in the "more setting" button on the Project properties, so I didn't see it. Shame on me, I was thinking the ClickOnce was the publish on the build menu.

Answer (score 2):

Can be seen in any assembly information file, I think it is pretty much self explaining..

```
// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

The only thing to note here is that assembly information does not have to be identical to the entire **app version which you can see in the click-once dialogs**.. to further explain: 
App version 5.1.5.3 might be using an assembly with version 1.0.0.0 
and also.. 
App version 2.0.0.0 might be using an assembly with version 19.2.5.1 
When installed on a machine the app has its own version and the assemblies have their own versions.

Comment: So, when did the assembly version can be other than 1.0.0.x? When and how it is decided? There is no point having a 1.0.0.13 assembly name after I published. I really don't understand how it works...

Comment: You must distinguish between file versions and product versions. an assembly can be used in many apps and app can use many assemblies.
read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.aspx

Comment: You should also note that version of an assembly is not just some metadata you can play with :) for that you have the product version which can be seen in the click-once dialogs.

Comment: I, just found a full publish menu in my project properties. I do not know this part till now.